# How to alter rendered commerce line item on order entity view?

Tags: commerce

I need to add a column(a "checking logistics picking" link) to each line item on order page(i.e. user/%user/orders/%commerce_order page), but I cannot make it done.
I tried hook_entity_view_alter and hook_block_view_alter, but seems they can only alter order entity view, cannot alter line items part of the order.

How to alter line item on order page? 
It became urgent, please help! Thanks.

Comment: I am trying hook_views_post_execute, $view->result[0]->field_field_end_date[0]['rendered']['#markup'] = ..., but it's not displayed on the page. I guess I miss something. I see commerce_line_item.views_default.inc, but I don't know what should I do to alter the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is a bit late, but here is what I did to modify the line items on an order view.

For my example, I wanted the type field to be displayed, so I altered the view of the `commerce_line_item` entity using `hook_views_pre_view(&$view)`.  Here the code that have:

```
switch ($view->name) {
    case 'commerce_line_item_table':
        $view->display['default']->handler->options['fields']['type']['exclude'] = FALSE;
```

This is all I needed to do since type was already there in the `commerce_line_item_table` view defined in commerce_line_item.views_default.inc, but if you want to add a field to the view, it would look something like this

```
        $view->display['default']->handler->options['fields']['type']['id'] = 'type'; 
        $view->display['default']->handler->options['fields']['type']['table'] = 'commerce_line_item';          
        $view->display['default']->handler->options['fields']['type']['field'] = 'type';
        $view->display['default']->handler->options['fields']['type']['relationship'] = 'commerce_line_items_line_item_id';
```

Please note, that when you later the view for the user/%user/orders/%commerce_order page, it also alters admin/commerce/orders/%commerce_order/view since they both use `entity_view`